# Getting blank page after changing the deploy mode to developer

Tags: magento2

fresh installed Magento 2.2.3 with sample data everything worked fine. until I changed the deploy: mode to the developer. now it is showing a blank page, there is no error only blank screen.

refresh the cache, deleted all cache folders, generated folder and cleared pub/static folder too ( leaving .htaccess ) file. recompiled the code, ran setup upgrade commands but without any solution.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try enabling the developer mode to check the error(s) if any.

Also please try changing the permissions of the file and folder to the following:

from the root directory:

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

Answer (score 0):

You should enable exception printing by renaming `local.xml.sample` to `local.xml` in `pub/errors`. Also check exception and system log in `var/log`